# Phonegap Oauthio FB logout

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I have used **phonegap oauthio** plugin for social login

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap
```

It is dependent on inappbrowser. By using following code I have implemented fb login

```
OAuth.initialize('Public key');
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, result) {
  //handle error with err
  //use result.access_token in your API request
});
```

Inappbrowser is like a popup. After login it is hiding and displaying my app. This is perfect.
But when I logout from my app, **how can I logout from OAuth**.

Please suggest. Thanks.